# Updating only the last classification layer of TFLITE model

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm currently running inference via tflite on an edge device which needs occasional updating as I accumulate additional classified data for training. The edge device only has satellite comms, so any data sent to/from it can be very expensive. The model currently used is a mobilenet V2 100 architecture at 3.5MB, which is about the smallest I've been able to get it while keeping the accuracy high enough. My current idea on updating the model is to retrain only the final classification layer, extract the weights, send the new weights to the edge device via a binary, copy the old model contents to a new flatbuffer while overwriting the weights of the final layer, then saving.

I'm wondering if this is a valid approach? Am I missing/overlooking anything?

Here is the proof of concept I've written in c++:

```
    //load flatbbuffer binary
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open("model.tflite", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    infile.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
    int length = infile.tellg();
    std::cout << length << std::endl;
    infile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
    char *data = new char[length];
    infile.read(data, length);
    infile.close();

    //Unpack flatbuffer
    tflite::ModelT model;
    tflite::GetModel(data)->UnPackTo(&model);

    //load weights. For test model, buffer index of classification layer is 181  
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer_data = (model.buffers[181]->data);

    //load new weights from binary file sent to device
    std::vector<uint8_t> new_buffer_data = ReadBinary("new_weights_binary");

    //assign new weights to existing ones.
    model.buffers[181]->data = new_buffer_data;

    //Pack and save updated flatbbuffer
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder fbb;
    auto model2 = tflite::CreateModel(fbb, &model);
    fbb.Finish(model2,reinterpret_cast<const char*>(tflite::ModelIdentifier()));

    std::string filename = "new_model.tflite";
    bool result = SaveFB(filename.c_str(),
                        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(fbb.GetBufferPointer()),
                        (size_t) fbb.GetSize(),
                        true);
```